# The description of the carrierCode field in the On-Demand Flight Status API states

Tags: amadeus

The description of the carrierCode field in the On-Demand Flight Status API states that it should be a 2-3 character string.
[image]
However, when I checked the IATA codes, I found that they are only 2 characters long.
[image]
I am confused by the discrepancy of having 3 characters.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 types of IATA codes:

1. Airline Code (2 digits)
2. Airport and City Code (3 digits)

you will be able to find that in [IATA website](https://www.iata.org/en/publications/directories/code-search/) or Amadeus provide APIs to grab the IATA codes

- [Airline code look up API](https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/flights/api-doc/airline-code-lookup)
- [Airport & City Search API](https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/flights/api-doc/airport-and-city-search)